# ui-router: doesn't load states into state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to create such a schema:

[DOM schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hIoD.png)

**Navbar** state must be always inserted, it have our template and controller.

**Content** state must insert templates and controllers depending on URL path. Example:

mysite.com/  inserts main.html and mainCtrl.js into Content state.

mysite.com/articles inserts articles.html and articlesCtrl.js into Content state.

My actual try:

```
//app.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ui.router',
    'ngCookies',
    'myApp.content',
    'myApp.main',
    'myApp.navbar',
    'myApp.articles',
]);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'navbar': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/navbar.html',
                    controller: 'navbarCtrl'
                },
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/content.html',
                    controller: 'contentCtrl'
                }
            }
        })


//contentCtrl.js
angular.module('myApp.content', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('content.main', {
                url: '/',
                views: 'templates/content/main.html',
                controller: 'mainCtrl'
            })
            .state('content.articles', {
                url: '/articles',
                views: 'templates/content/articles.html',
                controller: 'articlesCtrl'
            }
    }])
.controller('contentCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

}
]);

//index.html
<body ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ui-view="navbar"></div>
  <div ui-view="content"></div>
</body>

//content.html
<h1>Content template</h1>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

I see Navbar and Content states, but main and articles don't load into Content state.

How to create this kind of schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the navigation must always be present in the page then you can do something like:

```
<body ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-include="templates/navbar.html"></div>
  <div ng-include="templates/content.html"></div>
</body>
```

Next, in your `navbar.html` template, include the controller directly from the view, so you won't need a special state for it:

```
<div ng-controller="navbarCtrl">
   <!-- THE ACTUAL NAVIGATION HTML -->
</div>
```

Now you should be able to manage only the "real" states of the application and you don't need the `content.` prefix before the inner states, and in `content.html` you already have the `<ui-view></ui-view>` container for loading the actual states.